# Trading balance between countries - Northwind database

Tags: sql, sql-server, northwind

I have quite a task to do, using old Northwind database, I need to create a trading balance for each country. Which means, I need to count, how much each country sold to each country, how much they've bought and what's the balance, on plus or minus.
I have a table `Countries` with columns '`CountryID, CountryName, ContinentID`'.
I'd prefer if countries would be named by their original name, not `CountryID`.

I have table `Suppliers` with columns like `SupplierID` with matching `CountryId`. The same thing goes for `Customers` table, `CustomerID` and `CountryId.`

So far I have this:

```
SELECT c.CountryID, SUM(CONVERT(money, (od.UnitPrice * od.Quantity) * (1 - od.Discount) / 100) * 100) AS ProductSales
From Countries c
LEFT OUTER JOIN Suppliers s ON c.CountryID = s.CountryID
JOIN Customers cu ON c.CountryID = cu.CountryID
JOIN Products p ON s.SupplierID = p.SupplierID
JOIN Orders o ON cu.CustomerID = o.CustomerID
JOIN [Order Details] od ON o.OrderID = od.OrderID
GROUP BY c.CountryID
```

RESULTS:

```
9   2072561.58
6   65322.04
7   56430.15
4   106925.77
19  412799.24
13  17205.45
5   200785.20
16  35966.40
17  272475.70
11  78850.80
20  2947015.56
8   406791.55
```

I don't think it gives me anything close to what I need, probably it's only the value of all sold products. I am stuck with this task, I'l provide any informations you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will look like as shown below (Sorry, I don't have this DB installed on my local box). May be it will help-

```
select
    fc.Countryname as FromCountryName,
    tc.Countryname as ToCountryName,
    SUM(CONVERT(money, (od.UnitPrice * od.Quantity) * (1 - od.Discount) / 100) * 100)
from Suppliers as s
inner join Countries as fc on fc.id = s.countryid
inner join Products as p on p.supplierid = s.id
inner join [Order Details] as od on od.productid = p.id
inner join Orders as o on o.id = od.OrderId
inner join Customers as cu on cu.id = o.customerId
inner join Countries as tc on tc.id = cu.countryid
group by fc.Countryname, tc.Countryname
```

We have `Group By` the data for `FromCountry` and `ToCountry`.

For second requirement as per below comments (Maybe below query not efficient in terms of performance) -

```
select
    max(fc.name) as CountryA,
    min(tc.name) as CountryB,
    BalanceAB = sum(case when fc.name > tc.name then (CONVERT(money, (od.UnitPrice * od.Quantity) * (1 - od.Discount) / 100) * 100) end),
    BalanceBA = sum(case when fc.name < tc.name then (CONVERT(money, (od.UnitPrice * od.Quantity) * (1 - od.Discount) / 100) * 100) end),
    SUM((case when fc.name < tc.name then -1 else 1 end) * CONVERT(money, (od.UnitPrice * od.Quantity) * (1 - od.Discount) / 100) * 100) as [Total(A - B)]
from @Supplier as s
inner join @Country as fc on fc.id = s.countryid
inner join @Product as p on p.supplierid = s.id
inner join @OrderDetail as od on od.productid = p.id
inner join @Order as o on o.id = od.OrderId
inner join @Customer as cu on cu.id = o.customerId
inner join @Country as tc on tc.id = cu.countryid
group by (case when fc.name < tc.name then fc.name+' to '+tc.name else tc.name+' to '+fc.name end)
```

Output -

```
CountryA    CountryB    BalanceAB   BalanceBA   Total(A - B)
US          UK          20.00       200.00      -180.00
```

Comment: Well it is something, but it returned an empty table :/ I've fixed your script a bit, mostly adding full column name, but it's still not working.

Comment: I think I made a mistake, I've aded wrong names to some id. Now it's working great! I've got a long list of countries with one side transactions. I think I'll take it from here! Thank you so much for help!

Comment: What if I'd like to reduce it? For example, I need to know how much US bought from UK, how much they've sold to UK, and what is total balance, and I want to do that for every country.
Right now It only shows what was total trading balance between FromCountry and ToCountry. I need it also the other way around (balance between ToCountry and FromCountry) and the results deducted.

Comment: nono, I want to make something like this:
Country A - Country B - BalanceAB - BalanceBA - Total
I need to find out how much they've sold, how much they've bought and if their balance is on plus or minus.

Comment: I will try later ( busy on another stuff).

Comment: I would really appreciate your help, only have couple hours to do that.